# How to check which errors I have in my Google API project?

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-api, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'd like to use [this](http://jhshi.me/2013/11/10/page-view-plugin-for-octopress/) plugin with my Jekyll site to show page views for each post/ page. So I installed the plugin and set up a service account for Google data API. The site is generating but I get no data from Google Analytics for my page views (it shows 0). On the projects overview page in Google Developer Console I see that I'm getting errors. But I can't figure out how to check these errors?

Is there any way to see what these errors are?

How can I check if Google API is working at all on my site?

Comment: What are the errors message in projects overview page in Google Developer Console ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Nevermind, I reset all configuration settings once again and it's working now. The problem was with permissions when you add a new user to Google Analytics account. I had only Read & Analyze, and it should be all four (Manage Users, Edit, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with permissions when you add a new user to Google Analytics account. I had only Read & Analyze, and it should be all four (Manage Users, Edit, etc.).